# Voltage control

Tags: voltage, mosfet, dc-dc-converter, control

I've been trying to design a control circuit to switch supply.

What I want to achieve?

I need 24V voltage for supplying an ultrasound sensor. There are two ways of gaining 24V: `VIN` is a physical 24V power supply and `24V_OUT` is a boost converter placed in the other part of the circuit. I assume that when I plug any voltage to the `VIN` connector I obtain this voltage in the output decreased by the voltage drop on the `D4` diode. For now, when I put 7.4V to the `VIN` input, I receive 1.8V in the output. I've checked the datasheet and threshold voltage of the Q3 transistor is typically 1.8V. Could you explain where had I made a mistake?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It won't work because you are using an N MOSFET as high side switch without a proper driver.

The gate-to-source voltage must be **positive** and greater than Vth in order for the MOSFET to "turn on". But in your case, it is approximately **-20.7** volts.

I would suggest using a P MOSFET instead. But remember typical P MOSFET Vgs_max ~ -20V, so you must protect the gate from overvoltage.

btw, I don't understand what you are going to achieve. The diode logic "automatically" choose the higher voltage source.

Comment: My main circuit can be supplied by either batteries or 24V power supply. Sensor is supplied just for measuring time and then it is switched off.

What if I short R3 to `VIN` like it is suggested in the comment below? Would it work?

Comment: If you do so, Vg = 24V, Vs ~ 24V => Vgs = 0V. Nothing happens.

Comment: So if I replace Q3 transistor by proper p-channel one would it work? I want to enable the output with a low state. I think that the `R3` resistor should be connected to `VIN`

Comment: Sure. There are several questions about using P MOSFET as high side switch on this site. I suggest you should have a read at them.

Comment: Long Pham thank yoy for your help and time.

One more question: should I replace npn tranistor into pnp?

Comment: Nope. For the setup above, the P MOSFET would be off, by default.

Comment: Ok. Just wanted to make sure that my circuit will work in reverse logic.

Answer (score 0):

If Q4 is off, you get 3.3V on Q3 gate. Q3 must have Vgs = 1.8V (approximately) to stay on. So, the source voltage is 3.3V - 1.8V = 1.5V (close to 1.8V you measure).

One partial solution would be to wire R3 to VIN instead of 3.3V, but you still would have a 1.8V voltage drop and get approximately 22.2V instead of 24V.